# Android Device-Device communication over the internet

Tags: android, adt, communication, p2p

I've been searching the last hour for the best\simplest model for implementing device-device communication in Android.

What I need to accomplish is very simple: I want device A to be able to send messages to device B, and the other way around (Like a simple chat).
Of course both devices must have my app installed.

What would be the easiest way ?

I would rather not use a dedicated server.

Communication will be over the internet (3G).

Thanks.

Comment: You can use push notifications via parse.com (they use GCM for Android devices). Will not be instant messaging but is rather simple. Otherwise I think http://quickblox.com/developers/Chat is useful, but have no experience with it so do not know how complicated it is to setup.

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look.